# Code::Blocks with default install is not pausing with "press any key to continue" at end of program

Tags: c, ide, codeblocks

I installed Code::Blocks 17.12 on Windows 10 x64 using the defaults along with the built-in MinGW.

I created a new "Console Application" project for C. I attempted to run the program (debug) and it complained that gdb was not configured in the settings. I went to `Settings > Debugger...` the IDE settings and manually set the path to `C:\CodeBlocks\MinGW\gdb32\bin\gdb32.exe` which allowed me to compile and run.

The problem I'm having is that I've followed all of the defaults but the program does not pause after completion. I know that this can be worked around but this question is specifically regarding why this feature of Code::Blocks is failing.

There is a option for this in the IDE which is enabled by default in `Project > Properties... > Build targets (tab) > Debug (target) > Pause when execution ends (checkbox)` which is enabled by default:

[image]

Why is this feature failing?

I can confirm that the program does function by adding `system("pause");` so it is not a runtime error.

The program is a basic "hello world" one:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    printf("Hello world!\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Here is my build log:

```
Active debugger config: GDB/CDB debugger:Default
Building to ensure sources are up-to-date
Selecting target: 
Debug
Adding source dir: C:\home\workspaces\learn-to-program-in-c\TestProject\Test\
Adding source dir: C:\home\workspaces\learn-to-program-in-c\TestProject\Test\
Adding file: C:\home\workspaces\learn-to-program-in-c\TestProject\Test\bin\Debug\Test.exe
Changing directory to: C:/home/workspaces/learn-to-program-in-c/TestProject/Test/.
Set variable: PATH=.;C:\CodeBlocks\MinGW\bin;C:\CodeBlocks\MinGW;C:\Windows\System32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH;C:\Users\Matthew D'Onofrio\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\opt\Cygwin\x86\bin;C:\bin;C:\home\opt\Cygwin\x86\bin
Starting debugger: C:\CodeBlocks\MinGW\gdb32\bin\gdb32.exe -nx -fullname -quiet  -args C:/home/workspaces/learn-to-program-in-c/TestProject/Test/bin/Debug/Test.exe
done
Setting breakpoints
Debugger name and version: GNU gdb (GDB) 7.9.1
Child process PID: 4092
[Inferior 1 (process 4092) exited normally]
Debugger finished with status 0
```

Comment: Could it be because you're running it under the *debugger*?